# How to assign a python object (such as a dictionary) to pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to set a cell in a pandas dataframe equal to a dictionary for rows in which another column in that same row equals 1. I am using `df.loc` to filter the rows. Since my dictionary has two keys, it only works if the filtering done by `df.loc` also has two keys. If it doesn't have two keys, I get `ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable`.

I don't see why these two things are related.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2], [0,3], [3,4]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])
#df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[1,2], [1,3], [3,4]], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])

df.loc[df["Col1"]==1, "Col2"] = {'key1': 'A',
                                 'key2': 'B'}

print df
```

If I uncomment the third line of code, I would like to produce the below results.

```
   Col1                            Col2
0     1  {u'key2': u'B', u'key1': u'A'}
1     1  {u'key2': u'B', u'key1': u'A'}
2     3                               4
```

Before this gets marked as a duplicate, I have seen other questions regarding this pandas error, but none seem to solve this issue specifically.

Comment: Beware! You are duplicating the references, so if you modify one, you modify all copies!

Comment: @coldspeed. That is fine. In reality there is only ever one `df`. I meant to imply if I uncommented the second, then the first would be commented.

Comment: I don't understand why you expect to get that output if you uncomment the third line of code.  In that case, why would `df.Col1[1]` equal `1`?

Comment: @andrew_reece my apologies. I had some typos in the code that I fixed

Comment: When I run your code on Python 2.7.12, it gives the expected output without an error.

Comment: @andrew_reece I am in python 2.7.11 and pandas 0.18.1

Comment: @andrew_reece Funnily enough, the first one does not work as-is for me.

Comment: @user2242044 I get issues running your code with the first `df`. Is this expected? Anyway, my answer works for both the `df`s in your question, so take a look.

Comment: @Coldspeed. Yes, the first df was set up to demonstrate the problem. You're solution does work, although I find the issue a little weird.

Comment: Weird.  I just made an environment with 2.7.11 and Pandas 0.18.1, and launched a fresh shell in that environment from the command line.  Code is still producing the expected output without error, using the `[1,2], [1,3], [3,4]` `df`.

Comment: `[1,2], [0,3], [3,4]` generates the error. You are using the `df` that works fine.

Comment: "If I uncomment the third line of code, I would like to produce the below results."  The third line of code is `[1,2], [1,3], [3,4]`.  When it is uncommented, it produces the expected results.  Anyway, I'm glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIUC, wrap the dictionary in a list, and pass it to `loc`:

```
df

   Col1  Col2
0     1     2
1     1     3
2     3     4

m = df['Col1'].eq(1)
df.loc[m, 'Col2'] = [{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}] * m.sum()

df

   Col1              Col2
0     1  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
1     1  {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
2     3                 4
```

This should apply to any result equally well. Just keep in mind that `[] * n` replicates the references, so you have the *same* `dict` object being assigned to multiple cells! Keep this in mind going forward.

There's an alternative if you want to avoid duplicating references - you can build a list with a *list comprehension*.

```
i = {'a' : 1, 'b' : 2}
df.loc[m, 'Col2'] = [i.copy() for _ in range(m.sum())]
```

If you have a nested dictionary, `copy` only performs a shallow copy, so use the `copy` module's `deepcopy` function instead:

```
from copy import deepcopy
df.loc[m, 'Col2'] = [deepcopy(i) for _ in range(m.sum())]
```

Comment: That is a creative way of dealing with the solution. It seems like a weird functionality of pandas though. I also though about storing serialized.